# How can I install vim-full in cygwin?

Tags: vim, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install VIM in Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/345180/install-vim-in-cygwin)

I have installed cygwin's vim package, but it is only vim basic, and I can't find vim-full in the package list when running cygwin's setup.

How can I install **vim-full** in cygwin?

Comment: Run `setup.exe` and select it from the list!

http://superuser.com/questions/345180/install-vim-in-cygwin

Comment: @CioroiuAdrian-Nicu That's how I installed vim, but vim-full is not in that list.

Comment: What exactly do you want from vim-full that is not available in [one of the two GVim packages?](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=vim) Did you try to install from sources?

Comment: `vim-full` is a Debian package name. That name is not used for any of the Cygwin Vim packages. The Cygwin `vim` package has everything needed to run `vim` in a Cygwin console; the `gvim` package has everything needed to run `gvim` under X.