# How to Add and edit a .vimrc file in cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin, python3

Recently I downloaded the cygwin file `setup-x86_64.exe` and run it, and I selected all the vim packages and install them as well. Now i'm trying to edit the vimrc file to install some Plugins, but when i type `:e $MYVIMRC` in vim, vim just opens a new file named **$MYVIMRC**.

Questions are:

1. where and how do i find and edit my vimrc to edit it and install the plugins I want?
2. Do i need to make a new `.vimrc`?

Acording to: 
[Install Vim in Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/345180/install-vim-in-cygwin?answertab=active#tab-top)
Cygwin does not have a `.vimrc` file.

**notes**:

1. I use a Windows 10 Machine, 64bit operating systems, x64-based processor.
2. I intend to program in Python3 and what to use vim as my text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to locate your home folder. For example open vim and enter the command :

`:!echo $HOME`

Then, you just have to put your .vimrc file in the right location which is `$HOME/.vimrc`.

Comment: The `!` is not necessary, since Vim has an internal `:echo` command and `$HOME` is an environmental variable that is visible within Vim.

Answer (score 1):

The `:edit` (`:e`) command does not expand environmental variables. Try this:

```
:exe "e " . $MYVIMRC
```

Make sure you include the space after the `e` before the `"`.

But the easiest way to do it is just use the `~` expansion that does work with `:e`:

```
:e ~/.vimrc
```